# Why elastic-search container memory usage keeps increasing with little use?

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I have deployed Elastic-search container in aws using eks kubernetes cluster. The memory usage of the container keeps increasing even though there are only 3 indices and not used heavily. I am dumping cluster container logs into elastic search using FluentD. Other than this, there is no use of elastic-search. I tried applying min/max heap size using `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`. It applies successfully but still, the memory usage gets almost doubled in 24 hours. I am not sure what other options do i have to configure. I tried changing docker image from `elasticsearch:6.5.4` to `elasticsearch:6.5.1`. But issue persists. I also tried `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50` java option.

Check the screenshot from kibana. [image]

Edit : Following are logs from Elastic-search start-up :

```
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,119][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,120][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,120][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 16777216, hard limit: 16777216
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,120][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example: 
    # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
    elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
    elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,120][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] If you are logged in interactively, you will have to re-login for the new limits to take effect.
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,397][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [38.6gb], net total_space [96.8gb], types [ext4]
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,397][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] heap size [503.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,469][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] node name [es-79c977d57-v77gw], node ID [qrCUCaHoQfa3SXuTpLjUUA]
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,469][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] version[6.5.1], pid[1], build[default/tar/8c58350/2018-11-16T02:22:42.182257Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-1032-aws/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.1/11.0.1+13]
[2019-03-18T13:24:03,469][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.oEmM9oSp, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
[2019-03-18T13:24:05,082][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-03-18T13:24:05,082][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-03-18T13:24:05,082][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [es-79c977d57-v77gw] loaded module [ingest-common] ....
```

Comment: The Elasticsearch documentation has sections on [JVM heap configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html), and [there are a couple of ways to specify this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/jvm-options.html).  It is a complex, but very observable, piece of software; "why does it do X" without any more context is pretty difficult to answer.

Comment: Elasticsearch requires to use at less 2GO so you should increase the min/max and put **-Xms2g -Xmx2g**. Not sure it solves your problem, but it's a recommendation.

Comment: @DavidMaze As per the documentation I tried setting heap size using `ES_JAVA_OPTS`. When the container starts, it uses memory based on heap size specified but later gradually the memory consumption increases.

Comment: @C.med Tried that. Also tried by keeping default values -Xms1g -Xmx1g. But the issue persist.

Comment: what metric is being displayed in this image?

Comment: @kellanburket It's memory usage by the ES pod.

Answer (score 3):

Pod memory usage in Kubernetes isn't equivalent to JVM memory usage--to get that stat you'd have to pull the metric from the JVM directly. Pod memory usage, depending on the metric you're querying, can also include page cache and swap space, in addition to application memory, so there's no telling from the graph you've provided what is actually consuming  memory here. Depending on what the problem is, Elasticsearch has advanced features like [memory locking](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration-memory.html#bootstrap-memory_lock), which will lock your process address space in RAM. However, a surefire way to keep a Kubernetes pod from eating up non-JVM memory is simply to set a limit to how much memory that pod can consume. In your Kubernetes pod spec set `resources.limits.memory` to your desired memory cap and your memory consumption won't stray beyond that limit. Of course, if this is a problem with your JVM configuration, the ES pod will fail with an OOM error when it hits the limit. Just make sure you're allocating additional space for system resources, by which I mean, your pod memory limit should be somewhat greater than your max JVM heap size.

On another note, you might be surprised how much logging Kubernetes is actually doing behind the scenes. Consider periodically [closing Elasticsearch indexes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html) that aren't being regularly searched to free up memory.

Comment: The pod gets killed if I set the memory limit. I am setting heap size 512 MB and limiting the memory to 1 GB. Still, it gets killed by OOM error. I also tried closing all the indexes.

Comment: are you getting the OOM error in java before the pod is killed or is the pod killed without a logging message?

Comment: can you add your ES start-up logs to the question? Specifically the line that says "JVM arguments" and any error messages you're receiving.

Comment: The pod gets killed without any error. The OOM error is being displayed by Kubernetes. I have added log messages in the question above.

Comment: your heap size is too small to lock your memory. follow the error instructions in your logs and add the correct lines to /etc/security/limits.conf.

Comment: when the pod gets killed without an error on k8s and your JVM max heap size is below the memory limit, that means that k8s killed the pod because you hit your memory limit not because your JVM hit its max heap size, though you could log your JVM memory usage to verify. So off-heap memory allocation looks like its the problem here.

Comment: You might also try setting `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M`

Comment: Yes. you are right. The heap size is not an issue here. Looks like swap memory issue. I tried following the logs but I am not able to set `ulimit`. I added the lines in limits.conf file but it's not in effect I guess.

Comment: I think the issue is being discussed on github as well. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3595